# wordpress wp_mail is sending my html message as a text attachment

Tags: wordpress

This is the code to send the mail:

```
$to = $_POST['leadEmail'];
$subject = "my subject";
$message = ( $_POST['leadEmailPref'] == "html" ) ? $messageh : $messagep ;
$headers[] = "From: My Name <ny_name@gmail.com>";
$headers[] = "Content-type: ".$_POST['leadEmailPref'] ;

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

When I go to my inbox, the message is sent as an attachment and I don't see the message. Obviously I don't want the attachment, and I want the person who receives the email to see the message immediately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `Content-type:` is wrong. It should be `text/html` or `text/plain`, not `html`.

`$headers[] = "Content-type: text/".$_POST['leadEmailPref'] ;`

Comment: Why aren't you escaping $_POST['leadEmailPref'] ?
People could insert extra email headers

Answer (score 2):

You should try:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );

wp_mail( 'To Email', 'Subject', '<h1>Html Email</h1>' );

function set_html_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}

remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );
```

Comment: how I can attach 1 table with dynamic data into email content ?